# Clickhouse | where IN condition with single value

Tags: clickhouse

Clickhouse client version : 1.1.54318
This is my query

```sql
SELECT toDayOfWeek(event_date) as dd,event_date,toString(toDateTime(toString(event_time))) as event_time,severity
from tbl_sla_alert 
PREWHERE sla_id = 94 AND  event_time >= '2018-02-27 14:55:00' AND (event_time >= '2018-02-27 00:00:00' AND event_time <= '2018-02-27 23:59:59') AND (dd in (4)) 
ORDER BY event_date,event_time
```

While executing this query I am getting following error :

```
DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, ::1. DB::Exception: Set for IN is not created yet!.
```

but I put more than 1 value into "in" condition it works perfectly.
Please suggest, Is it clickhouse bug or something I missed...

Comment: I got the same with 19.4.3.11

Answer (score 0):

Try use 1.1.54343 and later your error message currently not exists on Clickhouse Server sources and maybe it is currently fixed